# Page number in page footer changes for each new customer

Tags: crystal-reports, footer

Crystal reports 11.

I have read lots of solutions for starting the page number count for each new group. However, specifically for what I need I cannot find a solution.

My report has several customers (patients) and each customer has more than one page of records.

I need to display in "page footer" the page n of m, starting for each new customer.

So Customer 1. Pages 3
Customer 2. Pages 2

Page 1 would be 1 of 3
Page 2 would be 2 of 3
Page 3 would be 3 of 3
Page 4 would be 1 of 2
Page 4 would be 2 of 2

I created a group for my customer id. However, my problem is two fold

1) I do not want page n of m to display in group footer, half way up my report. I want it to display in page footer.
2) I cannot get page n of m to work as my example above. I get page 1 of 1 for every page when I tick "Page number after" in section expert (either in my group footer) or page footer.

I am guessing I need to alter my page n of m in page footer but don't know what formula to apply here to get the page number to start on a new customer but also take into account how many pages exist per customer.

thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

You will need to group your report on Customer ID, but it sounds like you have this already.  :)

Next open the Section Expert and select the Group Footer for the Customer ID group.  On the Paging tab check the check box for "New Page After", this will ensure that each customer begins on a new page.  Then check the check box for "Reset Page Number After", this will ensure that the page number resets to 1 when a new customer is printed on the next page.  You shouldn't need a formula for either property.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that shortly and let you know if it worked